# command to delete slected text portion in nano

Tags: nano

I am using nano editor for the first time. I know that CTRL + K will delete an entire line. But I am unable to understand how to delete a selected portion (selected using mouse) of the the text. is there any special command for the same?
I am using this under Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 2):

Start nano with the -m option, i.e.

```
nano -m my_file
```

This enables mouse support.

Now a a double mouse click places a "mark" at the point where the cursor is located, and "Mark set" will appear on the screen. To delete a multi-line piece of text, place a mark at the beginning of the text you want to delete, and a second mark at the end of the text to be deleted. Now Control+K will delete the "marked" text.

Comment: very useful answer!